# Fixed-height screen-sized view inside UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

1. I have a UIView layout that needs to scale to both 3.5" and 4" screens.
2. I need top-level view to be a subclass of `UIScrollView`, so that I can use libraries implementing keyboard avoidance (the screen has text fields).

The problem is that I can't size the inner `UIView` relative to `UIScrollView` using constraints only, at least not without code, which I'd like to avoid. If I try to pin top and bottom of the inner `UIView` to layout guides, IB thinks its height is 0, and indicates ambiguous scrollable height for outer view (because it can't figure out the height of the inner view).

How can I achieve this without resorting to fiddle with constraints in the code?

Comment: why you trying avoid from codding? it's the easy way i think. you need help with do it under code?

Comment: @DekelMaman I prefer layout logic in one place, either all IB, or all code. Otherwise it's hard to follow for people not familiar with codebase.

Comment: Ok if you can't figure it out only with constraints, for last option consider this: make two storyboards one for 3.5" and one for 4" when the app launch check which type the device and then load the correct story board, it's not so complicated and for sure will work great for you :)

Comment: @DekelMaman Ugh, even worse!

Comment: @DekelMaman Anyway I ended up writing keyboard-avoiding code that doesn't need a scroll view.

Comment: OK :) hop you get your goal